# Add Interval to date in HSQLDB

Tags: date, hsqldb

How can i add for example 1 month to a date (already in the db) in a HSQL database.

In MySQL it would be :

```
UPDATE TABLE_CA SET DATE_A = DATE_ADD(DATE_A, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE id = 45
```

This function is supposed to work in HSQL but i got the following error :

```
Object not found : DATE_ADD
```

I'm using hsqldb 2.2.6 and cannot find the way to do this. I also tried DATEADD() function with the same result.

Comment: HSQLDB 2.3.x allows the MySQL syntax in the MYS syntax compatibility mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to call a function, HSQLDB supports SQL standard `interval` literals.

```
UPDATE TABLE_CA 
    SET DATE_A = DATE_A + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
WHERE id = 45;
```